# Какие есть удобные программы для редакции файлов .po

Tags: gettext

poedit пробовал - неудобно, когда много языков - хотелось бы, чтобы программа сразу совмещала языки по коду, а не переключаться по файлам

Ну, и в идеале - это macOs и интеграция с джангой(это не обязательно)